# Remote desktop from ubuntu to windows

Tags: 11.10, windows, vnc, remote-access, crossplatform

I want to take remote desktop from ubuntu to windows xp and 7,I am looking for a solution i can install software over the air.

1. Vnc,Avoid installation of Vnc server in windows (policy problem)
2. Looking software like Dameware in software is installed over the air
   and removed backed after the job is done.
3. Should allow to control the current active desktop and interact with
   the user session.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows already has a remote access system that you can use and connect using `vinagre` application available for Ubuntu.

*Right click on **My Computer** > **Properties** > **Remote** tab*

[image]

You just need to configure it and ask the network administrator to redirect the correct ports to you Windows computer.

The necessary port is TCP 3389, redirect connections on this port to your TCP 3389 port in your computer and you will be able to use the `vinagre` (installed by default on Ubuntu 11.10) to remotely connect.

---

If you do not want to install any extra software [quicksharescreen.com](http://quickscreenshare.com/) should allow you to support a customer over a web based interface that run with Java.

Its still in beta fase but it should work.

Has an alternative you can use others, here is a list of sites that allow you to share a desktop over the web and are cross platform:

- [vyew](http://vyew.com/)
- [Google Remote Desktop
  sharing](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp)
- [Java Remote Desktop](http://jrdesktop.sourceforge.net/index.php)

Comment: need to access the same session to provide support from ubuntu to windows

Comment: try the others, one will I hope ;)

Comment: Looking for software

Comment: Dont see how installing software that uses another protocol different from installing vnc itself, would it make a difference only cause its not vnc??> Besides these are web based solutions, they are still software running on top of java / flash but work no different from any application that installs a server on your Windows computers.

Comment: Does not work on Windows 7 Home or Starter editions. It only works on Windows 7 Professional.